# mounting a samba share from another linux machine error "bad network name"

Tags: linux, samba4

I am using OpenSuse tumbleweed latest versions of everything.

This command updates the whole OS to the latest build.
zypper dup

So I disabled all the firewalls, temporarily.

```
mount  -t cifs -o "cred=/etc/samba/user.txt,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2" //192.168.2.3/web  /mnt/x

mount  -t cifs -o "user=user,pass=pass,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2" //192.168.2.3/web  /mnt/x
```

Both commands as well as dozens of other variations all result in the same errors below.

So I verified that /mnt/x exists and it does

I am doing everything as root so it is not a permission issue.

On a 3rd computer which has windows   Start-Run \192.168.2.3\web  and after entering the credentials all my files appear.

On the 192.168.2.2 I get an error

BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\192.168.2.3\web 
Also  "No such file or directory" even though they all exist.

This is plainly false as it works in windows

Also it isn't the password, because when I intentionally enter the wrong password it says permission denied.

192.168.2.2 is the client
192.168.2.3 is the server

Error

> mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8)
> manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

dmesg

```
[ 8817.231966] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.2.3\web 
[ 8817.236567] CIFS: VFS:  BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\192.168.2.3\web 
[ 8817.236775] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Comment: What error messages do you get for the two `mount` commands? What machine is `192.168.2.2` that you mention near the end of your question? What does `zypper dup` mean near the top of your question? Is the CIFS server Windows or Linux? Are it and your two clients domain joined to Active Directory?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/641245/edit). Don't put updates in the comments as they can get missed by others wanting to help

Comment: Please don't summarise the error message. What is the exact text, for each of the two `mount` commands?

Comment: Which `mount` command is that error message for? Look, please try and make your question readable. Put it in order so that it makes sense for someone to read. You wouldn't write a story Chapter 1, chapter 3, chapter 7, chapter 2.

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't put updates in the comments as they can get missed by others wanting to help